# Is it possible to have Mulitple APKs for specific Devices (not just configurations) in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, device

We have to work around an Android bug that happens only on devices of a specific brand.

Because the workaround is the definition of a service + specific xml config in the Android Manifest, I cannot switch it in runtime (it must not be specified in the manifest). Also I am aware that one can have multiple apks for a Play Store listing, but only for supported filters: different API-levels, screen config, etc. (see http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

What I want is 2 apks, 1 for every device except if they are from brand X and 1 that serves only brand X.

I tried in the PlayStore, but supported device option seems to affect all active apks.

Comment: "Because the workaround is a service I cannot switch it in runtime" -- probably you can. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain the problem, explain your workaround, and ask how to support both approaches (normal and workaround) from one APK.

Comment: I really dont think so as we are using OffHostApduService, which afaik is more of a hint to the OS as a service i.e. we do not need the service itself (it is an empty implementation), but what the service does to the OS (changes where APDUs are routed). The question was really not about the issue (which I very much doubt many people have run into, since our case is extremly unique), but if it is possible to provide different devices with different apks.

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is not possible, which is why I was suggesting that you pursue other options.

Comment: OK thanks, thats what I thought aswell, I just wanted to rule out all options

Answer (score 0):

i think its work using support screen for android devices.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

it's define on manifest file.

Comment: I need to filter specific devices like "HTC M8"

Answer (score 0):

On your Google Play Console, on your app inside the APK tab, you can see supported devices, there it says 'See list' click on that and you will see all devices.

From there you can pick any device you want and exclude it from downloading your app.

Comment: And how to do it if I want different apks for different devices (as stated in the question)?

Comment: you could upload different apk as different apps and configure them using this way

Comment: Yes but this exactly what I want to prevent.